# Find a field K where the vectors are linearly dependent in the vector space K^3

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-fields

My task is to find a field $K$ where the vectors $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        3 \\
        1  \\
        \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        4 \\
        0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$are linearly dependent in the vector space $K^3$
So far I thought about that its working with $Z_2$, but I'm not sure if its valid or if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* These vectors are linearly dependent iff the determinant of the matrix formed by their coordinates is zero. This will depend on the characteristic of $K$.

Solution:

> The determinant is $16$ and so the vectors are linearly dependent iff the characteristic of $K$ is $2$.
>  Note that when the characteristic is $2$, you don't need the determinant because the second vector is the zero vector and so the three vectors are certainly linearly dependent.